# Up-to-date Syncthing on Raspberry Pi

Tags: debian, apt, raspbian, arm

How can I get the current latest version of Synchthing on Raspberry Pi without building from source?

I'm running Raspberry OS on a Raspberry Pi 4 and everything is recently updated. Running:

```
$ apt search syncthing
```

Gives me

```
syncthing/stable 1.0.0~ds1-1 armhf
    decentralized file synchronization
```

Latest version of syncthing is v1.16.1 according to https://syncthing.net/

I know I can download the sources and build the binaries, but I would much rather install an up-to-date version using the packet manager.

There is an instruction to add apt sources for syncthing here https://apt.syncthing.net. But they never mention CPU architecture. I notice that where it normally says "buster main" or "buster stable" in my sources.list files, this one says "syncthing stable".
Will these instructions work for raspbian buster armhf (ARMv7)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so I tried the instructions for debian/ubuntu apt install at https://apt.syncthing.net and that worked. There is support for armhf architecture.

Just follow the instruction to install the gpg key and then add syncthing to the apt sources. Do an apt update. After that an apt search will show an up-to-date version (notice the armhf) and the install works normally.

```
$ apt search syncthing

syncthing/syncthing,now 1.16.1 armhf
  Open Source Continuous File Synchronization


$ sudo apt install syncthing
```

I also got it working with `systemd`, but those files are not included in the installation as I understand it. You have to get those files/info from the GitHub repository:
https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/tree/main/etc/linux-systemd

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as accepted otherwise the system will think it isn't answered :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to take the commands from https://apt.syncthing.net and replace the `https` with `http`. Then it worked to update syncthing to the newest version despite having a rather old version of Raspbian OS.

```
# Add the release PGP keys:<br>
sudo curl -s -o /usr/share/keyrings/syncthing-archive-keyring.gpg http://syncthing.net/release-key.gpg

# Add the "stable" channel to your APT sources:
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/syncthing-archive-keyring.gpg] http://apt.syncthing.net/ syncthing stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/syncthing.list

# Add the "candidate" channel to your APT sources:
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/syncthing-archive-keyring.gpg] http://apt.syncthing.net/ syncthing candidate" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/syncthing.list

# Update and install syncthing:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install syncthing
```